# SQLite DB is Duplicating a last record in Table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

how to prevent a `SQLite DB` to duplicate my record its actually duplicating a last record of my `Table` i have primary key don't want to make it **UNIQUE** Key.

```
public void AddCity(String cityname)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues _values = new ContentValues();

    try {

        _values.put("City_name", Cityname);
        db.insert(TABLE_City,null,_values);
        // Log.d("Record inserted",Cityname);
        db.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: A primary key is unique by definition.

Comment: but my last record is replicating why it should be enter once ? @CL

Comment: A primary key cannot be duplicated. Which column is the primary key?

Comment: private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CITY="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_City + "("
                 + KEY_CITY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                 + KEY_CITY_NAME + " TEXT not null" + ")";

Comment: Actually i have two City records but 2nd city name duplicated again it should not be replicated. 
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                jsonarray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);
                Cityname = jsonarray.getString(1);

                AddCity(Cityname);

             //   Log.d("City Names", Cityname);
            }

Comment: You already know about the UNIQUE constraint. It won't work if you don't want to use it.